# Azure Virtual Network Gateway - Access resources in other resource groups

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Let's take the following scenario:

- I have a resource group in the East Region with 1 VM
- I have a resource group in the West Region with 1 VM

Both of these VMs are only accessible via Private IP addresses. RDP via Public IP address is not an option. One would assume that in order for me to RDP to these machines, I would have to VPN into Azure's gateway first. However, I don't want to create a virtual gateway in every single resource group.

Is it possible for me to vpn into one resource (in one resource group), and access all of the machines in all other resource groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It's possible to do this with VNet peering(connecting VNets within **the same Azure region**). You could follow this to [implement a hub-spoke network topology in Azure.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke) In this case, the hub VNet is a peering VNet with **allow gateway transit** enabled and the spoke VNet is a peering VNet with **use remote gateways** enabled.

please note that you cannot use remote gateways or allow gateway transit with **global peering**(connecting VNets across Azure regions). Refer to [requirements and constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview#requirements-and-constraints) about global peering.

> To use remote gateways or allow gateway transit, peered virtual
>   networks in must be in the same region.

so you have to move the peering VNets in the same region if the two VNets in each resource group are not in the same region.

Another option will create a separate VPN gateway in another resource group but this is not your expectation. Note that

> A Point-to-Site client can only connect to resources in the VNet in
>   which the virtual network gateway resides.

Refer to VPN gateway [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-vpn-faq#can-i-configure-a-point-to-site-client-to-connect-to-multiple-virtual-networks-at-the-same-time).

Comment: The peering worked just fine. I had to enable “allow forwarding” on both VNets.

Comment: Really? If you have several spokes and require connectivity between spokes, You must configure the peering connections to "allow forwarded traffic". If you have one hub and one spoke, you do not need to enable it, afaik.

Comment: Odd. I definitely had to enable it in order for it work. Also, if you already have your global VNET configured, and vpn client installed, you have to re-download the VPN client again.

Comment: Yes, you have to redownload the vpn client to make the on-premise route update.

Comment: I see someone open an [issue](https://github.com/mspnp/architecture-center/issues/1051) for clear use of 'Allow forwarded traffic'.  I did not enable it when I tested it following this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-peering-gateway-transit).

Comment: I wonder if they made the change without informing the public. I spoke with a member of MSFT support team. He mentioned that I had to have `Allow forward traffic` enabled in order for it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vnet peering with `Use remote gateways` checkbox enabled. You need to peer the vnets together and check `use remote gateways` on the second vnet (one without gateway).

Reading:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview

Comment: So..1st, i should create a peer-to-peer virtual network. then, implement a hub-spoke network between the two? Is that correct?

Comment: order doesnt matter, really. you just need both ;)